# how to fetch firebase storage json file from client side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I saved a json file in google cloud storage, I want to fetch the file, read the json content and save the content to client indexeddb.

```
loadJSON(function(json) {
   console.log(json); // this will log out the json object
 });

var fileUrl ="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rwrwr-rwr.appspot.com/o/TestCatalog.json?alt=media&token=r545-54-54-54-45455"


function loadJSON() {

  var request = new Request(fileUrl);

  fetch(request, {mode: 'cors'}).then(function(response) {
    // Convert to JSON
    return response.json();
   }).then(function(j) {
  // Yay, `j` is a JavaScript object
   console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
  }).catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Request failed', error)
  });
  }
```

The fetch is producing this error

> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How could I fetch the firebase storage json file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code form the browser you have to enable cross-origin access on your Cloud Storage bucket.
For that you can use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) tool und run

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>
```

The cors.json file should contain the following content:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

You can find the documentation on that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files).

Comment: Are you sure that's going to affect the download URL generated by the Firebase Storage SDK?  That's what's being used here.

Comment: I don't think that will affect the download URL. As I understand the error indicates that the resource (bucket in this case) needs to be configured to provide the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header field with the response. That should be the standard cors behaviour: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Note that the token added to the URL BYPASSES ALL SECURITY RULES.  At this time I have yet to find a way, CORS or not, to access a Firebase Storage file that actually FOLLOWS the security rules.